# Get ID from elements parent and put them inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like know how can i get the values ID of 3 element parent when i click on the children elements, and put them inside an array.

```
  <div class="selected" id="1">
      <div>Click</divi>
   </div>
    <div class="selected" id="2">
       <div>Click</div>
    </div>
    <div class="selected" id="3">
       <div>Click</div>
    </div>

  <script>
      $('li').click(function(){
        /// ???
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: You realize that your HTML is invalid, right?

Comment: [a LI can't be in any kind of element, especially not a div](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html).

Comment: Unordered lists have a very specific structure. That isn't it.

Comment: Moreover, the jQuery script would not work without a $(function(){})

Comment: Ok sorry i'll change the <li> with the a div

Comment: @Flea777 No need for that if the script is after the elements.

Comment: @dystroy You're right, but it's not a good practice anyway.

Comment: @Flea777 Once again I disagree. Putting the script at the end of the body and not adding a useless event handler *is* a good practice.

Comment: @dystroy I don't personally like javascript code blended into html. But it's only a personal opinion, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all ids :

```
var ids = $('.selected').map(function(){ return this.id }).get();
```

This would build this array :

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

To get the id of the parent of the clicked element:

```
<div class="selected" id="1">
  <ul><li>Click</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="selected" id="2">
  <ul><li>Click</li></ul>
</div>
<div class="selected" id="3">
  <ul><li>Click</li></ul>
</div>
<script>
   $('li').click(function(){
      console.log($(this).closest('[id]').attr('id'));
   });
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it's important for you, as your HTML was obviously written for this question, but [a li element can't have a div element as parent](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html). This invalid HTML is enough to prevent the real "parent" to be the div.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/egogUQA/1)

Comment: yes exactly, for make an array is right, but my problem is that doesn't work if i return $(this).parent().attr('id')

Comment: @fabrizio I'm not sure I really get your comment. Can you check the updated answer ?

Comment: Thanks for the demostration, but it doesn't make an array of all the elements. example if i try to use your previus code like that
$('li').click(function(){
  $('.selected').map(function(){ return     $(this).closest('[id]').attr('id'); }).get();
});

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('li').click(function () {
        var IDArray = new Array();
        $('.selected').each(function (Mindex, Mval) {
            IDArray.push($(Mval).attr('id'));
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var arry = new Array();
$(".selected").each(function(){
  arry.push(this.id);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var ary = new Array();
    $("div.selected").each(function(){
      ary.push(this.id);
    });
});
```